# Custom workflow and document generation

Tags: workflow, alfresco, activiti

I have situation where user needs to enter some data in alfresco, let's say on form (project name, start date, project author...). After user enters those data and some manager (project manager) review those data a document (.pdf or word) needs to be generated with those data and some other statics data.

I am alfresco novice and i would appreciate any guidance on how this can be done in alfresco.

Regards,

Aleksandar

Comment: I guess you need to dive into developing for Alfresco. You shouldn't expect that people will just hand you the code. First try it yourself, go through the Wiki and take a training....then post your 'problems' here :)

Comment: I didn't expect to someone write down a code form me. Because I'm new in Alfresco and don't have time to studying entire alfresco (project deadlines) i just asked if someone more experienced in alfresco can give me some basic guidelines on wich part of alfresco to get my attention on (does forms are created as part of web project-wcm part of alfresco, can document be generated using my data and so on...) I also try it myself and read wiki also, but i was not very clear so i asked. Thank's anyway. ;)

Answer (score 1):

As for forms, you can look at the [forms developer guide](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Forms_Developer_Guide). You should probably add a custom data model which holds all of the information for you.

And then after that, you should create a [custom workflow](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Workflow), which would take your form data and make a PDF out of it and then send it further down to PM for review. You could probably use the Review workflow that comes out of the box and customize it for this purpose, and there are a lot of examples on [webscripts](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Web_Scripts) on the [alfresco](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki) wiki and [forums](https://forums.alfresco.com/en/).

If you're an average developer, it shouldn't take you more then a couple of months (by my estimation) to get into the API specifics and work your way through to this.

Comment: Thanks man on your help. I have make deep dive and my workflow is in progress. :)

Comment: Well congratulations, I'm glad I could help. Ask away if you need more help.